# Given $p \rightarrow q$ and p are true, show $q ∨ r$ is true using rules of inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a question from computing mathematics which I am not really able to prove.

Given that $p \rightarrow q$ and $p$ are true, show that $q \lor r$ is true  using rules of inference.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To help with searching, I think _interference_ should probably be _inference_.

Answer (score 2):

Use $p \rightarrow q$, with $p$, to get $q$ by modus ponens (sometimes called $\rightarrow$-elimination.)

Then, from $q$, infer $q \lor r$, by the rule of inference known as $\lor$-introduction.

So you should have four lines in your proof: the first two being premises, the third should state $q$ for the reason given above, and the fourth "therefore $q\lor r$," for the reason given above.

Comment: Can you do it for me in a proper way so i can copy it down to my school assignment?

Comment: No Kiva. I've given you everything you need to know to construct the proof: *everything*. It's *your* assignment, so you should expect to have to do *some* work.

Comment: @amWhy +10 for "No Kiva. I've given you everything you need to know to construct the proof: everything. It's your assignment, so you should expect to have to do some work." sadly I can only award one point.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this in an expanded way to benefit anyone reading this, seeing that the person who asked the question is no longer registered on MSE.
There are multiple ways to *formally prove* something, and they are what govern the principalities of logic itself. Rules of inference. In this case, the one in question is *Modus Ponens* or (translated) *Mode of Affirmation*. It is stated as follows
$${\phi \vdash (p \to q); \phi \vdash p} \over {\phi \vdash q} \tag{MP}$$
If it is proven that $p$ implies $q$, then it is proven that $p$, we can **infer** $q$. There is also another rule of inference which can be called into question
$${\phi \vdash p} \over {\phi \vdash p \lor q} \tag{I $\lor$}$$
It says that if $p$ is proven, then it can be inferred that $p$ or $q$ is true. Knowing this, we can construct a formal proof.

*Proof of...* $\phi \vdash q \lor r$:
\begin{gather}
p \to q \\
\\
p \\
\\
q \tag{By MP} \\
\\
q \lor \lambda
\end{gather}
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
Lets break down the proof... since we're already given through the question that $p \to q$ is true, and that $p$ is also true, then these are free points. We apply the (MP) rule that we just learned, and then push for the (I$\lor$) rule that we also just happened to know to arrive at $q \lor \lambda$ with $\phi + \{\lambda\}$ being the same as $\phi$.
Hope this helped *someone*. :)